# how to apply the css to images with id like img120 in div having class 'open'

Tags: html, css

```
<div class='cluster' id='12' 'style='width:350px;min-height:150px;border:4px
solid #339966;'>
    <div class='image' style='width:150px;height:150px;border:2px solid
black;float:left;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px'>
    <img id='image1' src='server/php/files/image.jpg' style='width:140px;height:140px;float:left;'>
    <img id='image22' src='server/php/files/image.jpg' style='width:140px;height:140px;float:left;'>
    <img id='image45' src='server/php/files/image.jpg' style='width:140px;height:140px;float:left;'>
</div>
</div>
```

> [image: show image in this format]

help me

Comment: Abit more information including code would be helpfull here.

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Your image already has styles, so what more do you want? Please clarify! By the way, your html really could do with some whitespace between its attributes.

Comment: I don't see any `class="open"`?!

Comment: More information please, than this in title.

Comment: sorry class name is cluster

Comment: Deedar, you only try to explain your question in your tittle and the tittle doesn't make that much sense.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
$('#img120').css({ 'display': ' inline-block', 'padding-left': '177px' });
```

if starts with img and the number changes try like this

```
$('img[id^="img"]').css({ 'display': ' inline-block', 'padding-left': '177px' });
```

if you want ends with 120

```
$("img[id$='120']").css({ 'display': ' inline-block', 'padding-left': '177px' });
```

Comment: sir images are fetched from data base and they having different ids.

Comment: see updated code or please explain clearly

Answer (score 1):

1. Your question is totally incomplete.
2. Your html tag ids are different as compared to your question.

As for as I have understood your question, You want to ask that how you can apply some css to inner elements wrapped in tags. 
If I take your question, that there is a div having class `cluster` and in that div you have images having `id="120"` like this

```
 <div class="cluster">
     <img src="some src" id="120" />
     <img src="some src" id="120" />
     <img src="some src" id="120" />  
</div>
```

Then you can write css like

```
<style>
.cluster #120 {
 /* Your css properties */
 width:140px;
 height:140px;
 float:left;

}
</style>
```

If you want to put a style to all images in div class `cluster`, you can do it like this

```
 <style>
.cluster image {
 /* Your css properties */
 width:140px;
 height:140px;
 float:left;

}
</style>
```

By doing this you will not have to give style property to each image.

Comment: no sir the images are fetched from data base with different ids...

Comment: Id is unique and should not be assigned to multiple (DOM) elements on the same page. If you want to apply one style to multiple elements use a class for this: `<img class="img120" .../>` and the CSS rule `.open .img120 {...}`

Comment: @Deedar then simply use the second approach which I mentioned. See my updated answer